# How to prove the relationship between expressions and eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an expression:
$\boldsymbol{F}=\frac{B_{11} B_{22}-B_{12} B_{21}}{\left ( {B_{11}+B_{22}+ j \left ( B_{12}-B_{21} \right )} \right )^{2}}$

where $\boldsymbol{B}$ is a 2×2 Hermitian Matrix, 
$\boldsymbol{B}$=\begin{bmatrix}
B_{11} & B_{12}\\ B_{21}
 & B_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
The eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{B}$ are $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$, $\lambda_{1}<\lambda_{2}$,let $r=\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{2}}$. $j$ is the imaginary unit. $j \left ( B_{12}-B_{21} \right ) >0$. 
How to prove that $\boldsymbol{F}$ increases with $r$ ?
I have no idea how to decompose $\boldsymbol{F}$ or to transform $\boldsymbol{F}$.
For example $\boldsymbol{B}$=\begin{bmatrix}
34.9823 & 7.7554 -26.2325j\\ 7.7554 +26.2325j
 & 22.2571
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: What is the quantity $j$?

Comment: Imaginary part or imaginary unit?

Comment: Sorry, my bad , imaginary unit @NDewolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the formulas for determinants and traces in terms of eigenvalues (and noting that the determinant and trace are contained in the numerator and denominator respectively) you can rewrite $F$ as follows:

$$F=\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+j(B_{12}-B_{21}))^2}$$

Dividing both numerator and denominator by $\lambda_2^2$ gives you an expression in $r$.

However, you want to find that $F$ increases if $r$ does while the expression above shows the opposite, since the denominator contains the square of $r$. Perhaps you meant $r=\lambda_2/\lambda_1$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer @NDewolf